# How to Read XML Child

Tags: c#, xml, api, rest

Whats the best way to read the credentials token from this XML as a string?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableausoftware.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableausoftware.com/api http://tableausoftware.com/api/ts-api-2.0.xsd">

<credentials token="090834586395787390244234">
    <site contentUrl="GPS_Test"/>
  </credentials>
</tsResponse>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using the following code.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(responseFromServer);
            var value = document.Descendants().Single(i => i.Attribute("token") != null)
                           .Attribute("token").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, but "best way" is Always in the eye of the beholder...

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(youXmlString);
    var value = doc.SelectSingleNode("/credentials").Attribute("token").Value;
```

Comment: Hi, is this using Linq? Its telling me that Xml.Linq does not contain a definition for SelectSingleNode